# Trouble reading a file with logstash using a very basic configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, syslog, logstash, grok, kibana

I have used Logstash in the past, however it has been a while and this is the first time I have attempted to read from a file.  For the life of me I have been spending hours on what should be an absolutely simple task.  Instead of reading an entire log I am simply starting with something small and building my code off of it.

My log's file name is /home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/sample.messages

and the content of it looks like this:

```
Jan 15 00:33:48 "POST /service.php?session_name=sample_name HTTP/1.1"
```

My logstash file looks like this:

```
input {
   file {
      path => "/home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/sample.messages"
   }
}

filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => "/home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/patterns"
    match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{GREEDYDATA:message1}"]
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

finally I am referencing this code using this path:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx256m -Xms256m -jar logstash.jar agent -w 1 -f /home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/syslog.conf
```

Syslog.conf is in that directory and I have verified the path to the patterns folder, as well as the sample.messages file.
The odd thing is that it actually does parse that *occasionally*.  Like 1 in 20 times.

Im almost positive this is a bug in logstash however I would like to run it by the community in case I am missing somethin.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance
Cole

I have updated the code with this:

```
input {
   file {
      path => "/home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/sample.messages"
      type => syslog
      start_position => "end"
   }
}

filter {
if [type] == "syslog" {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => "/home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/patterns"
    match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{GREEDYDATA:message1}"]
  }
}
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

To cover all of my bases(adding a tag and setting the file input to end.  It still isn't working.
Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Cole

Answer (score 4):

Ben Lim mentioned that Logstash writes to a position database for file inputs and so reading through the file input tags in the documentation I figured out a way to finish my test environment.

```
input {
   file {
      path => "/home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/sample.messages"
      type => syslog
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   }
}

filter {
if [type] == "syslog" {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => "/home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/patterns"
    match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP} %{NOTSPACE:hostname1}/%{NOTSPACE}"]
  }
}
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

As you can see here in the input section I directed the database writes to /dev/null.  This forces logstash to read the test file every time regardless of wither it thinks it has been updated or not.
It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Do your logs write to "/home/shoresc/Desktop/logstash_config/sample.messages" after you starting the logstash?

The default Logstash File API reads file from the end of the file, so it will not read the previous log. You need to specify the [start_position](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.2/inputs/file#start_position) and it will read from the start of the file.

Comment: In this particular instance I am reading a completely static log that only contains a single line to simply build off of before transitioning the input from File to UDP. This is to get the Grok/Regex down first. That is what is so weird. It is literally a single line in the log file(sample.message). SYSLOGBASE should detect Jan 15 00:33:48 and GREEDYDATA is simply a Grok binding wildcard for the rest of the line .*

Comment: As you say, your log is completely static. So you need to add "start_position" to start reading log from the begenning at the file input.  Remeber to delete or rename your log file because once you have start to monitor a file before, logstash will keep the lines it read before in its database. You can refer to logstash file input api

Comment: Thank You, you just gave me an idea to complete my test environment.  I defined start_position => "beginning"  and then also added sincedb_path => "/dev/null" to force logstash to not read the database.